# Springboot https service invocation issue

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting following error, for security reasons I have replaced actual hostname with 'host'

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://host.company.corp.ae:8243/ISCP.Integration/api/CRMDocument/CreateCustomerRejectionFeedback": Certificate for <host.company.corp.ae> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [host]; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <host.company.corp.ae> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [host]
```

during development using spring boot, while invoking https services of CRM system.

Any support would be appreciated

Comment: *Certificate for <host.company.corp.ae> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [host]* Looks like you certificate does not contain the name you are using

Comment: @jens, thank you very much for the reply. But we already have the host name in our cert store.

Comment: with the full name?

Comment: yeah, with full name.